# What is better way of using boolean value for conditional statement

Tags: java

I have a boolean variable `isExists`. I need to check if `isExists` is true then i have to perform some action otherwise i need to perform other action. I can write conditional code like following

**approach-1**

```
if(isExists){
//perform use previous interest
}else{
//create new interest
}
```

**approach-2**

```
if(true == isExists){
//perform use previous interest
}else{
//create new interest
}
```

In some books approach 2 is used and in others approach-1 is used.

**What is the difference and which one is better between these two way of checking conditional statement for boolean**

Comment: I would use `if (((true == isExists) == true) == true)`, just to be really sure ;-)

Comment: what is the difference? Well there is no difference. Same difference :)

Comment: That said, using `if (exists)` or `if (isExisting)` would be even better. isExists doesn't look like correct English to me.

Comment: @JBNizet And it correct english to me it is  `if(isExists()){}`  ;)

Comment: with 18k reputation, I seriously think OP has incidentally asked this question by mistake

Comment: in java i would use the first approach only - the second one seems to be used in javascript quite often

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if(isExists)` this is enough and meaning full.

`if(true == isExists)` here you are checking `isExist` with `boolean` `true` again. No need redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

In java if your variable is primitive 'boolean' than it is file but if it is a object of Boolean class than please beware about NPE

Below code can cause NPE.

    `Boolean b = null; // Not a primitive boolean. 

    if(b) {

    System.out.println("It is true");

    }else

    System.out.println("It is false");`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isExists){
//perform use previous interest
}else{
//create new interest
}
```

is enough. Thats the advantage of having a boolean variable. If you have only a single one to check, just specifying the name is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The result would be the same in both approaches.

It's usually considered better form to use the former, though, for a couple of reasons:

- `isExists` is in itself a `boolean` value - there's no need to compute another one
- The former appraoch seems more natural when read out aloud (or in your head)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isExists)
```

Because it assign true by default to the variable

Answer (score 0):

in other words. its just a condition evaluation. The boolen is a boolen is a boolean. So, you dont compare a boolean (true) with true again to find out weather it is true or false. 
it doesnt hurt, as in, the compiler doesnt complain but it is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Version 1 is more readable, especially if we change the name to `exists`

```
if (exists) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> if(condition)

this checks if the condition is true. basically it does this( i.e. if your boolean is true):

> if(condition==true) -> if(true==true) by reading the boolean's value

So for a boolean, it will take it's value and check it against true. Both of your approaches are good, but conventionally the first one is used, since a boolean is named in such a way expressing a fulfilled condition.